# Make XML documentation reference to a field of class

Tags: c#

How to make reference from XML comment of `UpdateChanged` to `Long1` field?

```
public sealed class SystemConfiguration
{
    public long Long1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Make reference to Long1
    /// </summary>
    public bool UpdateChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `<see cref="SystemConfiguration.Long1"/>`.

Visual Studio generates an XML documentation file where each member is assigned an unique ID. You can check the rules for ID generation at:

[Processing the XML File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx)

In this situation the full ID that will be generated is `F:YourNamespace.SystemConfiguration.Long1`. However you can use the shorter version because you are in the same class.